# How to get result of a thread in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I have written a function which It is doing the Fibonacci calculation. I wanted to start and execute it with CreateThread as a thread. Finally, I want to save the result of the thread (the Fibonacci) and show it in the console. What is the problem with my code? It doesn't work properly. It starts the thread, but I don't know how should I store the result of the thread and show it.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

DWORD WINAPI Fibonacci(LPVOID arg_repeat) {
    DWORD dwValue = *(int*)arg_repeat;

    if (dwValue < 3)
        return 1;

    return Fibonacci((int*)dwValue - 1) + Fibonacci((int*)dwValue - 2);
}

auto main(int argc, const char* argv[]) -> decltype(0) {
    DWORD dwFibonacciValue;
    std::cout << "Fibonacci Value: ";
    std::cin >> dwFibonacciValue;

    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThreading = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Fibonacci, &dwFibonacciValue, NULL, &dwThreadId);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreading, INFINITE);

    std::cout << "Fibonacci Result: " << dwResult << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hThreading);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to wait, until the thread has done its job and not exit main by calling   `WaitForSingleObject(hThreading , INFINITE)` before closing its handle.

Comment: please replace "What is the problem with my code?" with a description of the problem ;). You must know more than what you wrote, otherwise how do you know that there is something wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend having a closer look at the documentation. You're misusing the return value of `ResumeThread` for sure.

Comment: You need to wait for the thread to complete, and then you need to get the thread's exit code. Also your argument passing to the function is completely wrong. What do you think `(int*)dwValue - 1` does? Clue, not what you think! You are trying to learn too much at once. You need to master basics before you attempt threading. Try to make `Fibonacci` work without any threads before attempting to add a thread. It's also a big mistake not to do any debugging. Make sure that you become proficient in using your debugger.

Comment: Seems like you would benefit from `std::future` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future). It is the standard library answer for your problem without relying on windows APIs

Comment: too many errors in code. at begin `Fibonacci` completelly wrong. you need something like `DWORD WINAPI Fibonacci(PVOID arg_repeat) {

 return (ULONG_PTR)arg_repeat < 3 ? 1 : 
  Fibonacci((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)arg_repeat-1)) + Fibonacci((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)arg_repeat-2));
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong beause `(int*)dwValue - 1` is not a valid pointer.

You should separate the thread function from the fibonacci function. There will be much less dubious and wrong casts and code will be much clearer:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

// Clean and easy to read fibonacci function without fancy casts
DWORD Fibonacci(DWORD dwValue) {
  if (dwValue < 3)
    return 1;

  return Fibonacci(dwValue - 1) + Fibonacci(dwValue - 2);
}

// Thread function
DWORD WINAPI Thread(LPVOID arg_repeat) {
  return Fibonacci(*(DWORD*)arg_repeat);  // the only cast int the whole code
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) -> decltype(0) {
  // it's 'int main', not 'auto main'
  DWORD dwFibonacciValue;
  std::cout << "Fibonacci Value: ";
  std::cin >> dwFibonacciValue;

  DWORD dwThreadId;
  HANDLE hThreading = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread, &dwFibonacciValue, 0, &dwThreadId);
  WaitForSingleObject(hThreading, INFINITE);

  // get return value of the thread (your actual question)
  DWORD dwResult;
  GetExitCodeThread(hThreading, &dwResult);

  std::cout << "Fibonacci Result: " << dwResult << std::endl;
  CloseHandle(hThreading);
  return 0;
}
```

There is no error check whatsoever in this code for clarity.

Other detail:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread, &dwFibonacciValue, NULL, &dwThreadId);   
//                                               ^ you should provide a DWORD
//                                                 here and not a pointer
```

should be

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread, &dwFibonacciValue, 0, &dwThreadId);
```